# pointer from integer without a cast (C programming) - simple error

Tags: c, string

```
char str1[20] = "Something";
char *str2 = "Random";
strcat(str1, str2[1]);
```

It gives the error  pointer from integer without a cast 
why is str2[1] treated as an integer?
so what should I do if I want to strcat individual elements in a string
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because an element from a `char` array *is* a `char`, which is an integral type. If you want a pointer to the second element, try `str2 + 1` or `&str2[1]`.

Comment: Brace yourself for another question when the OP's program croaks after attempting to write to unallocated space.

Answer (score 0):

With str2[1] the 2nd character is meant (starting at index 0), which is the 'a' in 'Random'.

If you want the complete string you need to write str2 instead of str2[1].

Answer (score 0):

`strcat` is expecting pointers to chars, but `str2[1]` is a `char` value,
modify it to be `&str2[1]` to get back a pointer to the second char in `str2`.

Answer (score 0):

`str2[1]` is of type `char` while in the `strcat()`, a `char *` is expected. Here you should have used `str2 + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

`str2[1]` is a `char` which is promoted to an `int` according to C type promotion rules. If you want to append a single character to a string, try the following:

```
int len = strlen(str1);
str1[len] = str2[1];
str1[len + 1] = '\0';
```

In other words, `strlen` only concatenates two strings, not a string and a character.